# AWS Amplify Auth without hosting on AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Hope you are doing well. My development team for a side project is trying to build out authentication for a web application within AWS (we currently use Firebase for Auth, but we want to keep as much of our implementation in AWS for better centralization. There are definitely tradeoffs in any decision). We are aware that AWS Cognito exists where you can create user pools and support authentication that way. There was a solution that kept popping up regarding AWS Amplify Auth as a "[hopefully] straightforward solution to setup authentication on the AWS side". Outta curiosity, are we required to deploy our web app thru AWS Amplify to use AWS Amplify Auth or is that not necessarily a pre-requisite? The documentation didn't seem to suggest something like that, but I had trouble finding an example on GitHub which clarifies. Could anyone provide some insight? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to deploy your web application through aws-amplify. You can use the API endpoints to leverage Cognito as the authentication provider with aws-amplify. You can have your own sign-in, sign-up auth pages as well.

Please refer to the setting up auth [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/react/prev/build-a-backend/auth/set-up-auth/)